# Nginx Configuration:504 Gateway Time-out error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tcp

We are using Nginx as a Load balancer.
Nginx having IP address of :10.110.0.200 and 
address of host machines are 10.110.3.20|10.110.3.21

this is the configuration file:

```
upstream test1 {   server 10.110.3.20:xxxx; }

server {

  listen               10.110.0.200:80;             server_name test1.xyx.com;

  location /  {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass         http://test1;

  }  }
```

We are getting an error message

> *798 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting
>   to upstream, client: 10.100.88.210

Any leads on this?

When we do curl for

> curl -v http://10.110.3.20:xxxx
>   * couldn't connect to host
>   * Closing connection #0 
>   curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't connect to the backend directly using curl, the problem isn't an nginx config problem, but instead something lower-level.  I'm going with firewall misconfiguration -- it's the catch-all problem in these situations.

Comment: we opened the ports on Nginx server To allow access from the nginx to the nodes(where application is) for the port range 30000 - 40000 (tcp only).

Comment: Does we need to add Firewall configurations(switch level), nginx server and applications are in different networks ?

Comment: I have no idea what you have to do, since I don't know your network.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. It's Firewall issue.

Comment: Score one for the Womble Crystal Ball.  Get yours today, wherever sysadmins gather to drink heavily and tell war stories.